Send messages via WhatsApp with personalized links
I am creating a script that retrieves data from a spreadsheet and generates a message using openpyxl and pyautogui, but when clicking on the send arrow... nothing happens.
import openpyxl
from urllib.parse import quote
import webbrowser
from time import sleep
import pyautogui

# Open WhatsApp Web and wait
webbrowser.open('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
sleep(15)  # Increase wait time if necessary

# Load the Excel spreadsheet
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('/home/cauademartin/PycharmProjects/controle/dados/Enviar.xlsx')
sheet = workbook['Sheet1']

# Iterate over the rows of the spreadsheet
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    name = row[0].value
    phone = row[1].value
    message = row[2].value

    # Format the link for WhatsApp
    whatsapp_link = f'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={phone}&text={quote(message)}'
    print(f'Opening link: {whatsapp_link}')
    webbrowser.open(whatsapp_link)
    sleep(20)  # Adjust the wait time as needed

    # Locate the arrow and click
    try:
        arrow = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('/home/cauademartin/PycharmProjects/controle/Scripts/seta.png', confidence=0.7)
        # Adjust the confidence if needed
        if arrow:
            print(f'Arrow located at: {arrow}')
            sleep(10)
            pyautogui.click(arrow[0], arrow[1])
            sleep(5)
        else:
            print('Arrow not found.')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error locating or clicking on the arrow: {e}')

    # Wait until the message is sent
    input('Press Enter after sending the message...')

